# How will salesforce handle non english characters in subject line of email to case

Tags: language

I have set up email to case, some of my customers will reply in language other than english (say chinese, etc).

I have set up case queues based on keywords or unique number they send in the subject line. So how will salesforce handle this and how it will affect the cases sitting in proper queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are using the Case Assignment Rules?

From my experience you have to use the language in your assignment rules, although numbers should work fine. This does mean your assignment rules can get quite heavy to maintain plus you will need help with the wording unless you speak all the languages.

We have regional email addresses that help us route the Case based upon email used, but obviously this has it's own maintenance as well.